# How to search and replace text in a file from a shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a shell script that does a search and replace inside a configuration file upon start-up.

The string we're trying to replace is:

```
include /etc/nginx/https.include;
```

and we want to replace it with a commented version:

```
#include /etc/nginx/https.include;
```

The file that contains the string that we want to replace is:

```
/etc/nginx/app-servers.include
```

I'm not a Linux guru and can't seem to find the command to do this.

Comment: This is really more appropriate to serverfault.com, imho.

Comment: I don't see why it is appropriate for serverfault.  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with servers.  It belongs on superuser.  Voting to close as such.

Comment: /bin/sh or bash or csh or any other shell are Turing complete languages. Why don't you think that "How to achieve X in language Y?" belongs on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perl -p -i -e 's%^(include /etc/nginx/https.include;)$%#$1%' /etc/nginx/ap-servers.include
```

If the line might not end in the `;`, use instead:

```
perl -p -i -e 's%^(include /etc/nginx/https.include;.*)$%#$1%' /etc/nginx/ap-servers.include
```

If you want to preserve the original file, add a backup extension after `-i`:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's%^(include /etc/nginx/https.include;)$%#$1%' /etc/nginx/ap-servers.include
```

Now, explaining. The `-p` flag means replace in-place. All lines of the file will be fed to the expression, and the result will be used as replacement. The `-i` flag indicates the extension of the backup file. By using it without anything, you prevent generation of backups. The `-e` tells Perl to get the following parameter as an expression to be executed.

Now, the expression is `s%something%other%`. I use `%` instead of the more traditional `/` to avoid having to escape the slashes of the path. I use parenthesis in the expression and `$1` in the substituted expression for safety -- if you change one, the other will follow. Thus, `%#$1%` is actually the second `%` of `s`, followed by the desired `#`, `$1` indicating the pattern inside parenthesis, and the last `%` of `s`.

HTH. HAND.

Comment: +1 for the solution and for using another better character for this case (%) instead of the more traditional /

Answer (score 3):

> sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' config.txt

This replaces all instances of foo (case insensitive) with bar in the file config.txt

Answer (score 2):

Check out [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```
sed -i -r 's|^(include /etc/nginx/https.include;)$|#\1|' /etc/nginx/app-servers.include
```

`-i` means do the substitution in-place and `-r` means to use extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd pathname
for y in `ls *`;
do sed "s/ABCD/DCBA/g" $y > temp; mv temp $y;
done
```

This script shold replace string ABCD to DCBA in all the files in pathname